# Proving homomorphism from functions

Tags: functions, computer-science

I am really struggling to grasp the concept of homomorphism as it has been poorly explained to me in courses, and I have not been able to find any clear examples of how to actually classify a function correctly. For instance, I have the function:

substract, that takes a list of integers $[x_1,...,x_n]$ as input and computes the result as a function of: $$x_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n x_i,\quad n > 0.$$

So with an example this would be:

$\operatorname{substract}([19,5,8]) = 19 - (5 + 8) = 6$.

But how should I approach showing whether this is a $homomorphism$ or not? From my understanding a $homomorphism$ is suc that I can find an operator $\oplus$ so that:

$f(x_1 * x_2) \mapsto f(x_1) \oplus f(x_2)$

For which $*$ resembles the concatenation operator on list structures.

But what would be the best case to prove an example as the one provided above? I have to classify a series of such functions with various signatures, but I want to understand the **HOW** I would go about doing this, as I clearly (and hornestly) cannot grasp it.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043456/which-operator-oplus-turns-a-function-f-into-a-monoid-homomorphism-from-l), since I wasn't 100% sure.

In order for $f$ to be a homomorphism, we must define the algebraic structures first, which is straight forward.

Let $L$ be the set of all finite lists and denote the list concatenation operator by $*$ and denote $[]$ as the empty list. Then the triplet $(L,*,[])$ forms a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), since

- $\forall a,b,c \in L: (a *b)*c=a*(b*c)$ (associativity)
- $\forall a \in L: a*[]=[]*a$ (existence of the identity element)

If we omit the existence of the identity element, then $(L \setminus \{[]\},*)$ would form a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

Since $f:L \to \mathbb{R}$ only holds for $n > 0$, our domain is $L \setminus \{[]\}$, and $(L \setminus \{[]\},*)$ is a semigroup. Now, we need to find a semigroup $(\mathbb{R},\oplus)$ such that $f$ defines a (semigroup) homomorphism.

Thus,

$$f(x*y)=f([x_1,\cdots,x_n]*[y_1,\cdots,y_m]) = f([x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m]) \\ \iff x_1-(\sum_{i=2}^n x_i + \sum_{j=1}^m y_j)=x_1-(\sum_{i=2}^n x_i + y_1 + \sum_{j=2}^m y_j)=x_1-\sum_{i=2}^n x_i-y_1-\sum_{j=2}^m y_j \\
\iff f(x) - f(y)$$

And therefore, $\oplus$ must be substraction "$-$". However, $(\mathbb{R}, -)$ is not a semigroup, since "$-$" is not associative ([here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subtraction_on_Numbers_is_Not_Associative) is a proof).

We can conlcude that given $f$ as it is defined, we can not endow $\mathbb{R}$ with a structure which makes $f$ a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing question. A homomorphism is a concept in algebra describing mappings which preserves the algebraic structure. To talk about homomorphism, you need an algebraic structure, (e.g. groups, rings, modules, vector space), and a homomorphism is something which preserves the operation of that structure.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I understand you input here, but let me try to emphasize. The function substract here takes an input which is a list of integers $[x_1,...,x_n]$. It then maps this to the result given by the $x_1 - \Sigma_{i=2}^n x_i$. My question is then how I can formally figure out to show if the structure is preserved? My problem is I do not understand how to actually go about showing this is the case.

Comment: Ok, my point was to talk about structure preserving maps you need to be clear what algebraic structure you're talking about. For example, all linear maps, such as the linear functional you gave, are homomorphisms between vector spaces.

Comment: Yeah I can see your point. I added the structure to the original question :) thanks for pointing it out, I am completely lost within this concept in general, which is probably why the structure was not evidentially clear to me, for the understanding of the question I ask.

Comment: I'm not sure what your difficulty here is. Where did you encounter this problem? Is it from a linear algebra class?

Comment: Computer science :-) my issue is that the curriculum does not explain this concept in any detail with examples or anything. The only thing I have is that it must satisfy: $f(x * y) = f(x) \oplus f(y)$, so when dealing with concrete examples where I need to prove whether a function is a homomorphism, I do not understand how I should engage it.  I may add that the $*$ operator is a concatenation above here (which I assume may be valuable).

Comment: apologies, homomorphism means something rather different in math! Be careful with the wording in your question, you said $f(x*y)\mapsto f(x)\oplus f(y)$ which is (I think!) not the same as $f(x*y) = f(x)\oplus f(y)$. Given list A,B, concatenating them and applying subtract surely loses information compared to applying subtract to A, B separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120253/discussion-between-steve-s-and-newlearner).